# JSF/Richfaces/A4j ==> component/field conversion and reRendering problem

Tags: jsf, richfaces, lifecycle, rerender

I have an input field in a JSF Page like the following (maps to BigDecimal on backing bean)

```
    <h:inputText disabled="#{volumeBean.grossVolumeDisabled}" id="grossVolume" size="10" validateOnExit="true" value="#{volumeBean.enteredGrossVolume}" >
    <a4j:support ajaxSingle="true" event="onblur" ignoreDupResponses="true" oncomplete="checkFieldValidation(this)" onsubmit="updateDirty()"/>
    </h:inputText>
```

And an a4j:commandButton to "refresh" all the data from the database on the page:

```
    <a4j:commandButton accesskey="T" action="#{volumeBean.revert}" button-type="ajax" disabled="#{volumeBean.revertDisabled}" id="volumeBean_reset"         immediate="true" reRender="volumesTable" value="#{msg.button_RESET}"/>
```

Here are the steps to reproduce my problem:
And please note that the error occurs regardless of whether there is a reRender attribute set on the a4j:support

Here are the steps to reproduce - just to clarify further:

1. navigate to the screen where the BigDecimal input field exists
2. type aa into the field (should be a number but put non-numeric characters purposely)
3. tab off the field
4. notice that an error is reported 'aa' is not a valid netVolume
5. click on the RESET button
6. all of the changed fields have their original values EXCEPT those that have non-numeric data entered
7. unless the user manually deletes the non-numeric data in the fields or refreshes the entire screen, the "bad data" sticks

Answer (score 0):

When you do a reset, you fire an Ajax request, the entire form is submitted and you get validation error again. So the field still has the old (incorrect) value.

Comment: The reset button has 'immediate="true"', so it should be bypassing validation.

Comment: Because conversation fails, the incorrect value is kept inside submittedValue in the component. You are correct, conversation/validation is not processed when immediate="true", but when the page is rendered, the value from submittedValue is used. You need to clear submittedValue.

Comment: how can one automatically or programmatically clear submittedValue?

Comment: Look in JSF API, component.getSubmittedValue()

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the parameter `ajaxSingle="true"` to the button.  I've found that `immediate="true"` is not adequate for bypassing validation on ajax components.

Comment: ajaxSingle will not skip validation. It means that only the current component will be processed, in other words, go through JSF life cycle.

Comment: I tried using    ajaxSingle="true" - didn't work.  the value is still cached on the client side somehow.